# why the DataGrid Sorting not working with AutoGenerateColumns="False"?

Tags: asp.net

my following code snippet doesn't allow sorting on DataGrid:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="tubewell" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSortCommand="sortColumn"
            >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="tubeWell_ID" DataFormatString="#{0:c}" 
                HeaderText="Tubewell &lt;/br&gt; ID"></asp:BoundColumn>
            <asp:BoundColumn DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" Visible="False">
            </asp:BoundColumn>
        </Columns></asp:DataGrid>
```

the following allows:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="tubewell" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="True" OnSortCommand="sortColumn"
        >

    </asp:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set SortExpression to the columns manually (SortExpression="myDataFieldInTheDb" ) when you have AutoGenerateColumns="false"